# Django - Update model field based on another field

Tags: python, django, orm, model, field

I am new to Django and Python and I want to do something I used to do very often in Java EE.

Consider the following model (only relevant classes):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    default_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    deposit = models.ForeignKey(Deposit)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)

    def item_updated(self, value):
        if self.unit_price == None:
            self.unit_price = value
```

What I want to do is that each time an `Item` is added to `SaleDetail`, update `SaleDetail.unit_price` with `Item.default_price` if `SaleDetail` is new or no `unit_price` is set.

What I used to do in Java POJOs was to include this logic in the setter method. I've tried using python properties to encapsulate the `item` property, but Django updates the field directly under the hood so this would break some automatic functionallity.

I've also tried to subclassing ForeignKey to accept a callback function but I couldn't find a way to call a method on the container class.

I want to do this so I can provide a default for the UI but I don't want to include this logic in the view logic, since conceptually I think this logic should be on the model (Server side)

Other use in this case would be to update totals for each sale detail and sale. I would like to calculate this BEFORE the user decides to save the sale, so save signals would not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "unit price" is a literally a function of two different fields.  As such I would tend to write it like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    default_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    deposit = models.ForeignKey(Deposit)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entered_unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)

    @property
    def unit_price(self, value):
        if self.entered_unit_price is None:
            return self.item.default_price
        else:
            return self.entered_unit_price

    @unit_price.setter
    def unit_price(self, value):
        self.entered_unit_price = value
```

Then use it like so:

```
print(sd.unit_price)
sd.unit_price = 500 
sd.save()
```

Comment: Now that I have more experience I can see that what I was trying to do does not makes sense in the django ecosystem, but since this answer my question correctly I am accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AníbalRivero Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki, what I wanted to do was to use the django admin as a generated UI for the end user, which is not a good idea since it is not meant for that.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you. We override the save method and check if there is a `pk`. If the `pk` is None, we know that the `SaleDetail` is new. Then, we see if there is a `unit_price`. If there is not a `unit_price`, we set it to the `Item.default_price`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    default_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    deposit = models.ForeignKey(Deposit)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure this is the first save (pk should be None) and there is no unit_price set
        if self.pk is None and not self.unit_price:
            self.unit_price = self.item.default_price
        elif not self.unit_price:
            self.unit_price = self.item.default_price

        # Call the original save method
        super(SaleDetail, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi @Michael , thanks for the answer. However, as I stated in the question, I need to do this BEFORE the user attempts to save the object.

Comment: The only other thing I can personally think of would be to add a method on the model which grabs the `unit_price`. It would use the same logic as the overidden save method, except that it would return the `item.default_price` in instances where it needs. I'm not entirely sure how you are collecting this information (a form?) so it is hard to help in your situation. If "SaleDetail" is actually a "line item" for a receipt, putting the method on the `SaleDetail` model should work.

Comment: Nice use of overwriting the `save` method