# Django - Relative Model

Tags: django

I have 2 models in my django app: Cats and Dogs.

Now I want to build a 3rd Model: Animals, that contains the same fields of the cats and dogs model.

I want that the changes I make to the cats and dogs models update the respective fields in the animals model.

Here is a short example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Dogs(models.Model):
    avg_height = models.IntegerField()

class Cats(models.Model):
    avg_height = models.IntegerField()

class Animals(models.Model):
    avg_height_cats = models.IntegerField()
    avg_height_dogs = models.IntegerField()
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to denormalise your data by having a separate model which stores information already contained in your other models?

Comment: I have lots of models with lots of fields and I want to consolidate everything in one big model for further processing

Comment: You may be better off doing ORM queries with aggregations of data from all of your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ library.

This way you can create a base Animal model and inherit your Dogs & Cats models from it. It will allow you to have some common fields in it.

Comment: I get an error that the fields of the animal model are missing if I try to save the cat or dog model and when I try to save the animal model nothing gets saved into the other 2 models. No way that 2 fields from 2 different models that are named differently will update each other using class inheritance only. I guess Ill have to make a signal for each model. Basically I want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632784/django-update-model-field-based-on-another-field

Comment: ok, it looks like not "relative model". It seems like you are looking for a some sort of "shareable mixin" between classes which will use overrided `save()` method which will do some calculations and can update local & other model fields based on the calculations.

more info at https://easyaspython.com/mixins-for-fun-and-profit-cb9962760556 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save

Answer (score 1):

Well... Even though I don't know why you have seperate models to store same data but if you have such implementation, I would prefer using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) to achieve such goal.

For example:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Dogs, dispatch_uid="blabla")
def update_average(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Animals.objects.filter(id=1).update(avg_height_dogs=instance.avg_height)
```

Or you can use Polymorphism as @alexandr stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59289456)

Comment: I will check out Polymorphism first, as I dont want to make a signal for each model. Thank you anyway

Comment: I get an error that the fields of the animal model are missing if I try to save the cat or dog model and when I try to save the animal model nothing gets saved into the other 2 models. No way that 2 fields from 2 different models that are named differently will update each other using class inheritance only. I guess Ill have to make a signal for each model. Basically I want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632784/django-update-model-field-based-on-another-field