# Django models update calculated field according another field

Tags: python, django

I use Django and I want update many records of my model by using a calculation like in SQL like that :

```
UPDATE table SET amount = pre_tax * 1.2 WHERE amount IS NULL;
```

I want do that with Django ORM. I didn't find any ways to do that.

This answer [Django - Update model field based on another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632784/django-update-model-field-based-on-another-field) don't use bulk update, I need a syntax that allows updating several records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [`F` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) and [`.update()` to update multiple records at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). The `F` expression allows you to reference an existing value in the row

```
Model.objects.filter(amount__isnull=True).update(amount=F('pre_tax') * 1.2)
```

Comment: Oh thanks you for answer ! Just at time where I found the syntax :) on the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db